# Use Ink Bottle Tool to outline shapes converted to symbol in Flash CS 5

Tags: animation, adobe-flash, cs5, symbols

I have been teaching myself Flash CS 5 and attempting to do some simple animations. I have created a simple bat drawing that I am attempting to animate.  I read that it is a good idea to break sections of the object to be animated into different symbols and labels in order to lock when needed. As such I converted the wings into symbols and distributed to different layers.  Now I want to change the color of the outline for the left wing to a light grey color to match the rest of the picture.  When I try and use the ink bottle tool it has no effect.

Is there another way to do this? How can I accomplish the needed result? I have tried editing that symbol/layer specifically with no effect.

Comment: Is there a stack exchange more specific to animation then this? Sorry if I overlooked it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symbols are a bit like folders - you'll need to double click (or right click / edit) the symbol to go into it and see the original "flat" shapes again.